Solving a recurrence by substitution method
I am trying to solve a recurrence question using substitution method. The question looks like

But I am unable to solve it. Could you please help me to solve this question.
I assumed Let, T(m) <= cmloglog(m). This is the value I got using method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119799/solve-the-recurrence-tn-2tn-2n-logn. But I am unable to solve it for both O-notation and omega-notation. Could anyone please provide insights on how can i solve it ? Please let me know if I have to add any more information.

What do you mean by "I am unable to solve it for both O-notation and omega-notation"? Have you checked the answer with the highest votes in your link?

Yes. So if we use induction method to prove this where we assume T(m) <= cmloglog(m) then with substituon method we get T(n) <= 2c(n/2)loglog(n/2) + (n/logn). I am unable to prove this is less than or equal to cnloglog(n). For O-notation.
